# Installing GDAL 2.3 in Python 2.7.15

Tags: python, gdal

I wanted to install latest version of GDAL (2.3) in Python 2.7.15 32 bits. I usually install the gdal core and bindings from www.gisinternals.com for my python version (msc 1500). However, for version of GDAL 2.3 there is only available for msc 1900 and 1911 which I dont know what version of Python correspond to, but not mine (maybe Python 3?). So, is there no GDAL 2.3 for version 2.7.15? Anyone knows?

Comment: https://www.gisinternals.com/query.html?content=filelist&file=release-1911-gdal-2-3-1-mapserver-7-2-0.zip has GDAL 2.3 in Python 2.7 32bit installer, the link is named GDAL-2.3.1.win32-py2.7.msi.

Comment: Yes, but according to the installation tutorials I have seen so far, you are supposed to install the version according to your compilation (msc): https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows

Comment: I think you're out of luck. The MSVC 2015/17 Python 2.7 packages are probably only there as they would get built by default for each compiler version. You will probably have issues if you try to use MSVC > 2008 packages.  I suggest either submitting [a ticket](http://gisinternals.com/issues.html), using miniconda/Anaconda or moving to Python 3 and accepting the fact that Python 2 is very nearly EOL and that people are going to start dropping support for it.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Out of curiosity, what determines de compiler version? I see for example that gdal 2.2.3 has versions for 1500, 1600, 1700, 1800, 1900 and 1911. For Python 2.7, either 32 or 64 bits, in Windows 7, it is 1500. What are the rest of the versions for? Other Operative Systems?

Comment: Try it and see, the major and minor versions are the same so it's only a subversion different. If it doesn't work then uninstall it.. it's a lot less drastic than dumping python 2.7 which, if you have ArcGIS, you can't do.

Comment: Can someone clarify me when the other compilator versions should be used? I mean, are they for newer OSs, for example? I use Windows 7

Comment: The compiler is matched to your installed runtime, for example if you have MSVC 2008 compiler you need to have MSVC 2008 runtime installed. You should try to have the same compiler and bitedness (32 or 64 bit) used for all products to ensure that the exposed interfaces can be located in the DLLs; you can't use a mix of 32 and 64 bit but a different compiler version isn't as drastic just slightly unadvisable.

Comment: Ok thanks, from what I have seen I haven't installed any MSVC runtime manually, or from other software, so I assume MSVC 2008 is the one that comes by default in Windows 7, then?

Comment: No.  It's because Python 2.7 is compiled using MSVC 2008 (1500) so any binary libs (i.e GDAL) need to be compiled with MSVC 2008.  Try MSVC 2015 or 17 (1900/1911) versions if you like. It may work for you, though I can tell you from experience, it's never worked for me, causes hard crashes and segfaults. But then again it's been a few years since I've bothered to try.

Comment: But if Python 2.7 is compiled with MSVC 2008 (1500), why are there so many other versions (1600, 1700, 1800, 1900, 1911)?

Comment: As I already said - "The MSVC 2015/17 Python 2.7 packages are probably only there as they would get built by default for each compiler version". i.e. the GIS Internals build system is set up to build the same set of libs for each compiler.  However, I did a quick google and found that it's not a hard and fast rule and so long as the extension library (i.e GDAL) is well behaved wrt to CRT shared memory, file handles, and env vars you may be able to use extensions with later runtimes.  If it's not you will get crashes.  More info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460.aspx

Comment: The reason the MSVC < 2015 builds were disabled is the older compilers don't support C++11 which is now a GDAL requirement https://github.com/gisinternals/buildsystem/issues/117